How to Retrieve Complete Transaction History and Earnings Data via OKX API
I'm working on a project where I want to retrieve all my transaction history and earnings data via the OKX API. My goal is to create an overview that allows me to track profits and losses from all my trading activities, deposits, withdrawals, and any staking/earnings data.
Here’s what I’m trying to accomplish:
1. Complete Transaction History:

I would like to gather all my past deposits, withdrawals, and trade history for various instrument types (e.g., Spot, Futures, and Margin).
I need to know if there's a way to efficiently paginate through all my transactions since I’ve been trading for over a year. Ideally, I'd like to fetch only the new transactions that haven't been retrieved yet.

2. Earnings and Rewards Data:

I would like to retrieve any earnings or staking rewards I’ve accumulated through OKX's staking programs.
Is there an API endpoint that provides a breakdown of earnings, bonuses, or any other rewards? How do I track these over time?

3. Bot Trade Information:

About a year ago, I started using a bot for automated trading. I'd like to be able to track the bot’s buys and sells over time. Is there a specific API that provides detailed trade information on these bot trades?

4. Automation Plan:

My plan is to run this app daily to automatically fetch only the new data (anything that hasn't been previously fetched) and store it locally for analysis.
Is there a way to ensure that I am fetching incremental data (to avoid redundant queries)?

Additional Details:

I’m already using the API endpoints for deposits, withdrawals, fiat transactions, and trade history, but I’m wondering if there are any better strategies or endpoints that would make this more efficient.
Any help with rate limits or best practices for handling large datasets over a long period would also be appreciated!

I have already written some code to interact with OKX’s API to fetch deposits and withdrawals, which works fine. However, I’m struggling with retrieving complete trade history and fiat transaction history, as the responses for those endpoints return errors or don’t seem to find any data.
For example:

Trade History: I'm using the /api/v5/trade/order-history endpoint, but it sometimes returns an empty result even though I know trades exist.
Fiat Transactions: The /api/v5/asset/fiat/orders endpoint seems to fail or return no data, and I’m not sure what parameters are required.

Here's the code I’ve been working with:
import time
import requests
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
from datetime import datetime
from urllib.parse import urlencode

class MyOKX:
    def __init__(self, api_key, api_secret, passphrase):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.api_secret = api_secret
        self.passphrase = passphrase
        self.base_url = "https://www.okx.com"

    def _get_server_timestamp(self):
        """Fetch OKX server time and return it in milliseconds."""
        url = f"{self.base_url}/api/v5/public/time"
        response = requests.get(url)
        server_time = response.json()['data'][0]['ts']  # This is the server time in milliseconds
        return server_time

    def _get_iso_timestamp(self):
        """Convert the server timestamp to ISO 8601 format with milliseconds."""
        server_time = self._get_server_timestamp()
        iso_timestamp = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(server_time) / 1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'
        return iso_timestamp

    def _sign_request(self, method, path, body=''):
        """Sign the request with the correct timestamp and generate the signature."""
        timestamp = self._get_iso_timestamp()
        message = timestamp + method.upper() + path + body
        mac = hmac.new(self.api_secret.encode('utf-8'), message.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
        signature = base64.b64encode(mac.digest()).decode('utf-8')
        return timestamp, signature

    def _get_headers(self, method, path, body=''):
        """Generate headers with the correct timestamp and signature."""
        timestamp, signature = self._sign_request(method, path, body)
        return {
            'OK-ACCESS-KEY': self.api_key,
            'OK-ACCESS-SIGN': signature,
            'OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
            'OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': self.passphrase,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

    def fetch_deposits(self):
        """Fetch deposit history."""
        path = "/api/v5/asset/deposit-history"
        method = "GET"
        url = f"{self.base_url}{path}"
        headers = self._get_headers(method, path)
        print(f"Request URL: {url}")
        print(f"Request Headers: {headers}")  # Print headers for debugging

        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        print(f"Response Code: {response.status_code}, Response: {response.json()}")
        return response.json()

    def fetch_withdrawals(self):
        """ Fetch withdrawal history """
        path = "/api/v5/asset/withdrawal-history"
        method = "GET"
        url = f"{self.base_url}{path}"
        headers = self._get_headers(method, path)
        print(f"Request URL: {url}")
        print(f"Request Headers: {headers}")  # Print headers for debugging

        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        print(f"Response Code: {response.status_code}, Response: {response.json()}")
        return response.json()

    def fetch_fiat_transactions(self):
        """ Fetch fiat transaction history """
        path = "/api/v5/asset/fiat/orders"
        method = "GET"
        url = f"{self.base_url}{path}"
        headers = self._get_headers(method, path)
        print(f"Request URL: {url}")
        print(f"Request Headers: {headers}")  # Print headers for debugging

        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        print(f"Response Code: {response.status_code}, Response: {response.json()}")
        return response.json()

    def fetch_trades(self, instType="SPOT"):
        """ Fetch trades for a specific instrument type (e.g., SPOT, FUTURES, MARGIN) """
        path = "/api/v5/trade/order-history"
        method = "GET"
        params = {'instType': instType}  # Specify instrument type
        query = '?' + urlencode(params)
        url = f"{self.base_url}{path}{query}"
        headers = self._get_headers(method, path + query)
        print(f"Request URL: {url}")
        print(f"Request Headers: {headers}")  # Print headers for debugging

        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        print(f"Response Code: {response.status_code}, Response: {response.json()}")
        return response.json()

# Example of usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    api_key = "your_api_key"
    api_secret = "your_api_secret"
    passphrase = 'your_passphrase'

    # Instantiate the class
    okx_api = MyOKX(api_key, api_secret, passphrase)

    # Fetch deposits, withdrawals, fiat transactions, and trades
    okx_api.fetch_deposits()
    okx_api.fetch_withdrawals()
    okx_api.fetch_fiat_transactions()
    okx_api.fetch_trades()

